# asking advice for the schduled task

Tags: asp.net

I am about to implement the schduled kind of task, not sure whether should implement in window sevice or window schduler.

The use case is, there will be one executable deployed on the mechine, which is attached to the scanner.  For every five minutes, the exe will be reading the scanned files from the specified folder and upload the files to the server.

What would be the best solution for this use case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a scheduled task. A windows service would have to be specially written, and this is perfectly suited for a simple job which runs at 5 minute intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some good comparisons here:

[windows service vs scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390307/windows-service-vs-scheduled-task)

Personally, I would use the Windows Service because it is easier to troubleshoot, locate the logs and restart if necessary.