# window service in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I need to create a service in Visual studio 2010 and C# which will see periodically in a specified folder that any new file exists since last time It(Service) checked the folder. If there exist any file, It will get uploaded to pre defined destination.

I need to save the credentials to connect to ftp in db access as well.

What libraries, classes should I use for this. Please suggest.

Comment: -1 You won't end up with a piece of software by posting a series of overly broad questions. Voting to close.

Comment: Please be more specific about the actual issues you are having. This is not answerable in its current state (Subjective and Argumentative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You technically don't need a service for this.  Just have a job which starts a program on the machine and use the [File System Watcher Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).  When it realizes that files in the directory have changed, run the code to FTP the file to the specified location.

You can use this to execute your FTP commands: [FTP Web Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)

Comment: What does it mean by  starting a job ? Actually both the source and desrtination locations are ftps

Comment: You can have a start up task which starts the program running.  That's all I meant.

Comment: you mean scheduling the application in Task scheduler ?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with File System Watcher if you're expecting high volume.  I'd suggest possibly using PInvoke and hooking up with [change journals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are very abstract, but i think its easy to formulate a solution for this.

Your application can be a windows form application for implementing the functionality, [Directory methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) should be of great help  in getting the new file,once file is found you can use [FtpWebRequest methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) to upload the file.

Create a Scheduled Task in your control panel and schedule the application to run according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi @Morpheus Instead of using scheduled application using task scheduler, Isnt it better to create a windows service so that If I need to install it on multiple systems, Then I dont have to schedule it?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow this should be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390307/windows-service-vs-scheduled-task

Comment: @DotnetSparrow I prefer scheduled task over windows service for this, I use windows service for applications interacting with database since its straightforward ftp upload i think scheduled task should do the trick!