# Scheduling a cron job in localhost windows

Tags: java, cron

I need to run a job in a scheduled manner, on tomcat server deployed on my local machine having windows OS .

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390307/windows-service-vs-scheduled-task could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about tomcat, but on Windows the way you schedule jobs is using the "at" command at the command prompt.

There is also another way, if you go to Start/Programs/Accessories/System Tools/Scheduled Tasks. (May vary depending on which version of Windows you have.)

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to use the underlying system's scheduler and prefer to go full java, some librairies offer cron-like scheduling capabilities, for instance [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).