# Best Practice: Converting an application to a service with a schedule

Tags: c#, service, xmlhttprequest

I'm a bit of a beginner as far as programming is concerned. And looking at stack overflow I haven't found anything that quite answers my question. 
I have created a C# console application that is used to push an XML file to a web service that I don't control. It does this by creating an http webrequest. The service will probably be running on windows server 2008, or a win 7 varient. Development is done in VS 2010.
My end goal is to run this program twice a day with little user involement. And I was told that services were the best way to do this. I know that services do not take user input and that outputs are usually to a log file. My console app dosn't take user input but must have the ability to C.R.U.D. files. Beacuse it creates and then reads an XMl file into the web request. If needed I should have no problems having it write any errors to a log file, but at current though it creates/sends an error report via email.

I have 2 questions:

Question 1:
I would like this service to call the application every 12 hours, Is it more reliable/better practice to use a service to determine when to run the application? Or use windows' built in scheduler, or a .net solution like quark? I'm looking for reliability and also, little user involvement. Kind of a set and forget deal.

Question 2: 
What would the suggested  best practice be for converting my program?
INFO: I have previously created a empty windows service that I would like to fold my application into. (This was done via tutorial, the service contains all that is needed to for a service but it dosn't do anything... yet! OnStart, OnStop, installer etc.) What would be the best way to do it? Should I call my application inside the service's OnStart() method? Our should I add the application as a dll to the service. It's not that I don't think I could do it. It's just my searches on the matter seem to point out that it would be better to just start from a service and add some code to that. My goal would be to minimise the code needed to convert this application.

Thanks for all your help,
Chris

Comment: Quick note: C# is C-Sharp. Just FYI.

Comment: @JClaspill - I "fixed" his lame attempt at humor.

Comment: Please don't put keywords in the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows service vs scheduled task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390307/windows-service-vs-scheduled-task)

Comment: For future reference this is the pound symbol - £

Comment: @ Steve Wellens: While my post did touch on this issue. I was also was trying to determine how best to procede with what I had. Are you suggesting that I just plug it into a schedular and be done with it?

Answer (score 2):

I like standalone programs run by the scheduler because they are easier to write and test.

Services would be more appropriate when they have to be running all the time...say to monitor something.

Comment: I'd agree here, at 12 hours between each run, the overhead of a service running all the time and doing nothing only detracts.  If it needed to run every 6 hours, that might be worth it, every 5 minutes service for sure... might depends on the specifics

Comment: I agree this is a good way to go. And it answers my first question. As far as my second question... if a service was necessary, would it be best to just call the application from the service. Or would it be better to rewrite the application as a service?

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: Personally running twice a day seems like a scheduled task type of operation

Question 2: I'd describe it as: more or less put the body of `static void Main(string[] args)` into the `OnStart` method.  Then also create a timer in `OnStart` which will call the trigger function in your class.  But then I've only stumbled my way through writing windows services so I'm not 100% certain on this advice...

One consideration might be whats the risk of *anything* failing in the process?  If there is a chance of an unhandled exception, the service will die and either would need special settings to restart it or complete error handling to be coded.  Where a scheduled task will always automatically retry at the next trigger interval.