# How to schedule a program to run only at specified time duration in C#?

Tags: c#

I have created a C# program to perform input output operations in windows. I want that program to be invoked at specified time interval e.g. (9:30AM-11:00AM) everyday.
How can we achive this?

Comment: a windows scheduled task?

Comment: If your application is constantly running, or is running as a windows service, use a `Timer`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Another alternative dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390307/windows-service-vs-scheduled-task